# Concat string with html element in react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

This might give a better idea, replace in paragraph, ' ==> " and highlight it

```
for (let i=0; i<orgString.length;i++) {
      changeVal.push("color:#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16))
      let spanStart = <span style={changeVal[i]}> '"' </span>
      if (orgString.charAt[i] === "'") {
        let newSubstring = orgString.substring(0,orgString.charAt[i]);
        orgString = newSubstring + spanStart + orgString.substring(orgString.charAt[i+1], orgString.length);
      }
    }
```

Trying to change the multiple values, so concatenating in same string and render it once entire string is iterated

But getting output with [object Object] where concatenated HTML element

Answer (score 4):

If the dynamic string to be concatenated is composed of *text*, use brackets inside of JSX:

```
const Snippet = () => {
  str = 'The world is new'

  return (<>
    {str}
    <p style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Every Morning</p>
  </>);
}
```

(also note that JSX elements styles' must be set with syntax like `style={{ styleProp: stylePropVal }}`, and you need to assign the function to a variable; `const () => {` will throw a syntax error)

Otherwise, you'll have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```js
const Snippet = () => {
  const str = 'The world <b>is new</b>'
  return (<React.Fragment>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: str }} />
    <p style={{ color: 'blue' }}> Every Morning</p>
  </React.Fragment>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<Snippet />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

But it'd be better to avoid that if at all possible - use text, state and JSX elements instead whenever you can.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Use React.Fragment:

```
const data = () => {
  str = 'The world is new'
  para = str + <p style='color:blue'> Every Morning</p>

return (
  <React.Fragment> 
    {para}
  </React.Fragment>
);
}
```

or

```
const data = () => {
  str = 'The world is new'
  para = str + <p style='color:blue'> Every Morning</p>

return (
  <> 
    {para}
  </>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this combination when mixing HTML tags with javascript variables

```
<li className="row"><strong> Alerts: </strong> <br/> {`${user.alerts}`} </li>
```